# Accessing public files via javascript SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on an application where a user can create a list, and share it publicly.  The contents of the list is rendered by my site as a webpage, but exists also as a text file in the users drive who created it.  Everything is handed by javascript, and works well, however I am currently using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope.

This is a very scary permission to have, so I would like to drop it.  However, when the user trying to read the file, if they only have the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope, the shared file (accessed by id) doesn't exist for them until I run them though the sharing flow.

My guess is that although this was a file created in my application, that file was never opened by the **viewing user** in my application, so it doesn't qualify under that scope.  This seems a bit silly, because anyone (even if they are not logged in as any user) could download the file from google using only its id.

I want to avoid running them through the share-link flow, because if the user hasn't logged into my application yet, they are more or less stranded at that screen.  The app isnt installed as a viewer for that filetype for them, so they aren't presented with it as a suggested app to use to open it.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there really no way to support this seemingly very common use case of enabling a user to share links to their files though the app open url?

I dont see why I should need full access to the user's drive as I'm trying to access a file that **isn't even in their drive.**

**Note**: I do also have the realtime-api mounted on top of the file, which is also working, but shoudln't really have anything to do with the basic sharing.

**Some relevant code snippets creating and setting permissions on the file:**

Create The File

```
gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
    var insertHash = {
        'resource': {
            mimeType: 'application/vnd.mysite.com',
            title: title
        };
    };
    gapi.client.drive.files.insert(insertHash).execute(next);
});
```

Grant Everyone Permissions

```
gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
    fileId: $scope.id, resource: {
        type: 'anyone',
        role: 'writer'
    }
}).execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Try to access the file as a viewer, fails with out `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope

```
gapi.client.drive.files.get({fileId: $scope.id}).execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    next(resp);
});
```